# Debugging AIR Projects by Clearing LSOs / applicationStorageDirectory / StageWebView Cookies

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cookies, air, flashdevelop

When using FlashDevelop to build and test projects for AIR for mobile, you can only programmatically remove my manually named LSOs by name between runs.

How do you clear the StageWebView cookies to test things like different Oauth2 redirect uris?

Also, is there a way to clear the applicationStorageDirectory?

I have a feeling I am doing this in a n00b way. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will have a better solution but I tend to `trace(File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath)` and manually remove the files.

Comment: Thanks for this -- I have already done this and deleted the .sol that I have found there ... I guess that there is a different place that the StageWebView cookies are being stored since no matter how many times I delete the com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile.sol the application logs me in and **returns my FacebookID #** without my having actually inputted any credentials (after the very first time I ran the program and logged in through the Web view).